# what is valid data for http post request for request content type application/json

Tags: rest, api

I have one rest api.
which accept application/json request for an http post method .
all post parameters are optional.
The question is what is considered valid request in that case.

1. No value
2. {}

The second option represent json with no value.
Which is best practice for api?